# Has sorting changed to show answer by asker at the bottom?

Tags: discussion, answers, sorting, self-answer

I have noticed lately that the answer sorting/ordering method has changed where if the user answered their own question that it now appears at the bottom of the answers rather than at the top.

I have found this rather annoying from a usability level as now what most likely is the most helpful answer is buried at the bottom when I am expecting it to be at the top. This has tripped me up recently when I thought the question didn't have an accepted answer and I was looking at "inferior" answers before I scrolled and noticed an accepted answer at the bottom of the page.

Doesn't making useful answers hard to find go against the sole purpose Stack Overflow was built?

Comment: Are you sure you are sorting answers by vote? Also self-answers were never at the top by default.

Comment: I'm using the default sort; haven't changed it; but definitely have noticed a difference in sorting lately.

Comment: Do you have a link to a self-answered question where the self-answer is at the bottom?

Comment: @Yannis Sure, here you go, one of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778477/how-to-make-custom-settings-data-available-globally-in-yii-2 - My answer appears at the bottom under two other answers that have 0 upvotes; not sure how this helps anyone.

Comment: It appears at the top for me @Brett. Please double check that you are [ordering answers by votes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wCeqI.png).

Comment: @Yannis It's ordering by the default, which appears to be the "Active" tab. I didn't reorder it when visiting the page.

Comment: "votes" is the default (you can verify that by visiting the site in incognito mode). When logged in, however, the site remembers the last order you picked. Which has confused all of us at some point or another.

Comment: @Yannis Hmmmmm ok, thanks for that. I will keep that in mind.